# Parsing Nested JSON with Flutter (Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the JSON Response I'm getting. I want to Parse the text which says "url" (With. I want to Get this Text)

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "attributes": {
              "Title": "My Story",
              "Story": "My story is about my life",
              "Image": {
                "data": {
                 "id": 1,
                   "attributes": {
                      "name": "lifeImage.jpeg",
                        "alternativeText": "lifeImage.jpeg",
                         "caption": "lifeImage.jpeg",
                         "url": "/uploads/lifeImage_0e9293ee8d.jpeg", <-- I want to Get this Text
                            "previewUrl": null,
                            "provider": "local"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "page": 1,
            "pageSize": 25,
            "pageCount": 1,
            "total": 3
        }
    }
}
```

I easily parsed the Title, Story with the Below Dart File.
But I'm not sure how can I parse the URL text (One with arrow marks says "<-- I want to Get this Text"). Since it's nested one I don't know how to do that. Please help me with this. Thanks

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

import 'StoryPage.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Stories',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const Homepage(),
    );
  }
}

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  Future<List<Story>> _getStories() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'https://exampleapi.com/api/stories/?populate=Image'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);

      List StoriesList = responseData["data"];
      List<Story> stories = [];
      for (var storyMap in StoriesList) {
        stories.add(Story.fromJson(storyMap["attributes"]));
      }
      return stories;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load stories');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('My Stories'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getStories(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return InkWell(
                    child: Card(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 32.0, bottom: 32.0, left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              snapshot.data[index].title,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          new MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => new StoryPage(
                                    snapshot.data[index],
                                    title: snapshot.data[index].title,
                                    body: snapshot.data[index].body,
                                  )));
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Story {
  final String title;
  final String body;

  Story({required this.title, required this.body});

  factory Story.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Story(
      title: json['Title'],
      body: json['Story'],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply parse them like this:

```
final url = json['image']?['data']?['attributes']?['url'];
```

here we're using question marks (?) in between, because we're not sure that each element is not null, for example, the `data` under `image` may be null, so by using question marks, we're staying safe from null exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: also, this is not a way i would suggest doing this, i suggest creating models for each layer and making a fromJson method for each one, etc.

Comment: Can you give some example? I'm new to Flutter.

Comment: please take a look [at this tutorial](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/parse-json-dart/#:~:text=use%20jsonEncode()%20and%20jsonDecode,the%20parsing%20code%20more%20robust)

Answer (score 1):

I took @Adnan approach and modified it little.

```
final ImageURL = json['Image']?['data']?['attributes']?['url'] ?? ''
```

Thanks to GitHub Co-Pilot.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this website to generate dart or any other language object from json.
you just need to covert it to null safety.

here a example:

```
class AnswerResponse {
  AnswerResponse({
    required this.id,
    required this.description,
    required this.isAccepted,
    required this.isMine,
    required this.media,
    required this.caseId,
    required this.voteUp,
    required this.voteDown,
    required this.votes,
    required this.user,
    required this.comment,
    required this.createdAt,
  });

  factory AnswerResponse.fromJson(final String str) => AnswerResponse.fromMap(json.decode(str));

  factory AnswerResponse.fromMap(final Map<String, dynamic> json) => AnswerResponse(
    id: json["id"],
    description: json["description"],
    isAccepted: json["isAccepted"],
    isMine: json["isMine"],
    media: json["media"] == null ? null : List<MediaResponse>.from(json["media"].map((final dynamic x) => MediaResponse.fromMap(x))),
    caseId: json["caseId"],
    voteUp: json["voteUp"],
    voteDown: json["voteDown"],
    votes: json["votes"],
    user: json["user"] == null ? null : ProfileResponse.fromMap(json["user"]),
    comment: json["comment"] == null ? null : List<CommentResponse>.from(json["comment"].map((final dynamic x) => CommentResponse.fromMap(x))),
    createdAt: json["createdAt"],
  );

  final int? id;
  final int? caseId;
  final int? votes;
  final bool? isAccepted;
  final bool? isMine;
  final bool? voteUp;
  final bool? voteDown;
  final String? description;
  final String? createdAt;
  final ProfileResponse? user;
  final List<MediaResponse>? media;
  final List<CommentResponse>? comment;
}
```

and to convert json string to dart object:

var data = AnswerResponse.fromMap(jsonString)